# Authorize Attribute not filtering on DbDataController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use the new MVC4 DbDataController to expose a restful data api.

My problem is trying to secure this.  I have created custom authorization attributes that derive from Authorize Attribute

```
public class AdminOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (!IsAllowed()) {
      filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Not logged in");
  }
  ...
}
```

And that works fine when applied to my normal controller actions.  I'm trying to use the same thing in my data service like this:

```
[AdminOnlyAttribute]
public class DataServiceController : DbDataController<AppBuilderDataContext>
{
  [AdminOnlyAttribute]
  public IQueryable<Thing> GetThings()
  {
    return DbContext.AllMyThings();
  }
}
```

You can see I've tried my attribute on both the controller and the action, but it's not firing for either one.  I've set a breakpoint inside my authorize attribute function, and it's not getting called.

I'm pretty sure Scott Guthrie said this was going to work.  Am I doing it wrong, or do I need a completely different method to secure these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with an `DataController` or any other type derived from `ApiController` your attribute must derive from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's quite a bit different from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.  There is nothing on the interwebs about this yet except from the very brief msdn acknowledgement of its existence.

My first question is, will this type of attribute also work on my normal mvc actions?  Or am I going to need a duplicate authorization attribute class there?

Comment: In the Beta, yes you will need to types of attributes, one for MVC controllers, another for API controllers. We're looking at improving this in the enxt drop.

Comment: I've decided to skirt around the problem by creating a custom RoleProvider and then putting this at the top of my DbDataController
`using AuthorizeAttribute = System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute;`
I can then put this on my data action (or class)
`[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]`

It doesn't do everything I need yet, but it's a start. In some cases I'll need to lookup the user record to check if they can access specific records, so this won't cut it.

It would be a lot niceer if the same MVC filters we have would work with these new controllers.